# LX Panel Menu flashes at startup and then disappears

Tags: lxpanel

After an upgrade my Raspberry Pi stopped showing the default desktop menu with the app launcher. The symptom was that the panel would flash briefly 4 times before disappearing.

Tracing it down `lxpanel` is failing to find a panel config file during launch.

Here is the output of the lxsession log (`/home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log`) l:

```
grep: /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/*: No such file or directory
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/usr/share/lxde/openbox/menu.xml"
** Message: 16:04:06.718: Connecting ...
** Message: 16:04:06.718: Status changed to down
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

** (lxpanel:1034): WARNING **: 16:04:06.841: init context: err:6 Connection refused

Assertion 'pthread_mutex_lock(&m->mutex) == 0' failed at pulsecore/mutex-posix.c:90, function pa_mutex_lock(). Aborting.
** Message: 16:04:06.927: app.vala:130: lxpanel exit with this type of exit: 6
** Message: 16:04:06.928: app.vala:148: Exit not normal, try to reload
** Message: 16:04:06.958: app.vala:76: Launching lxpanel 
** Message: 16:04:07.238: x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal
grep: /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/*: No such file or directory
** Message: 16:04:08.292: Connecting ...
** Message: 16:04:08.292: Status changed to down
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

** (lxpanel:1034): WARNING **: 16:04:06.841: init context: err:6 Connection refused

Assertion 'pthread_mutex_lock(&m->mutex) == 0' failed at pulsecore/mutex-posix.c:90, function pa_mutex_lock(). Aborting.
** Message: 16:04:06.927: app.vala:130: lxpanel exit with this type of exit: 6
** Message: 16:04:06.928: app.vala:148: Exit not normal, try to reload
** Message: 16:04:06.958: app.vala:76: Launching lxpanel 
** Message: 16:04:07.238: x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal
grep: /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/*: No such file or directory
** Message: 16:04:08.292: Connecting ...
** Message: 16:04:08.292: Status changed to down
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the missing panel configuration:

1. Run  lxpanel from the command line and edit the panel config using the ui. The config is saved to `/home/pi/.config/lxpanel/Default/panel`.
2. Copy that file to `/home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`
3. Reboot

Here is the contents of a panel file I generated in case you run into problems:

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
  edge=top
  allign=left
  margin=0
  widthtype=percent
  width=100
  height=36
  transparent=0
  tintcolor=#000000
  alpha=0
  setdocktype=1
  setpartialstrut=1
  usefontcolor=1
  fontcolor=#ffffff
  usefontsize=0
  fontsize=10
  background=0
  backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/background.png
  monitor=0
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=2
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=menu
  Config {
    image=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/my-computer.png
    system {
    }
    separator {
    }
    item {
      command=run
    }
    separator {
    }
    item {
      image=gnome-logout
      command=logout
    }
    padding=0
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=pcmanfm.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=lxde-x-terminal-emulator.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=lxde-x-www-browser.desktop
    }
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=wincmd
  Config {
    Button1=iconify
    Button2=shade
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=pager
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=taskbar
  expand=1
  Config {
    tooltips=1
    IconsOnly=0
    AcceptSkipPager=1
    ShowIconified=1
    ShowMapped=1
    ShowAllDesks=0
    UseMouseWheel=1
    UseUrgencyHint=1
    FlatButton=0
    MaxTaskWidth=150
    spacing=1
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=cpu
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=tray
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=dclock
  Config {
    ClockFmt=%R
    TooltipFmt=%A %x
    BoldFont=0
    IconOnly=0
    CenterText=0
  }
}
```